# Moving and optimizing svg coordinates to a grid in python

Tags: python, svg

I am working with .svg files exported from GIMP. I need the nodes on each path moved to the nearest vertex (on a 70px grid) and remove duplicates.

A sample .svg looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="1283.95mm" height="1037.04mm"
     viewBox="0 0 3640 2940">
  <path id="Selection"
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
        d="M 1475.00,205.00
           C 1475.00,225.21 1471.02,215.59 1471.00,231.00
             1471.00,231.00 1471.00,329.00 1471.00,329.00
             1471.00,331.56 1470.89,334.55 1471.65,337.00
             1472.95,341.22 1476.88,346.28 1481.01,347.99
             1484.25,349.34 1489.44,349.00 1493.00,349.00
             1493.00,349.00 1515.00,349.00 1515.00,349.00
             1515.00,349.00 1660.00,349.00 1660.00,349.00
             1662.50,349.00 1665.62,349.11 1668.00,348.35
             1682.12,343.87 1679.00,324.35 1679.00,313.00
             1679.00,313.00 1679.00,231.00 1679.00,231.00
             1678.98,215.59 1675.00,225.21 1675.00,205.25
             1675.00,205.25 1685.00,205.25 1685.00,205.25
             1685.00,205.25 1698.00,209.00 1698.00,209.00
             1698.00,209.00 1731.00,209.00 1731.00,209.00
             1731.00,209.00 1755.00,205.00 1755.00,205.00
             1755.00,205.00 1755.00,209.00 1755.00,209.00
             1754.97,222.24 1751.16,217.55 1751.00,229.00
             1751.00,229.00 1751.00,314.00 1751.00,314.00
             1751.00,314.00 1751.00,469.00 1751.00,469.00
             1751.02,484.41 1755.00,474.79 1755.00,494.75
             1755.00,494.75 1745.00,494.75 1745.00,494.75
             1745.00,494.75 1732.00,491.00 1732.00,491.00
             1732.00,491.00 1630.00,491.00 1630.00,491.00
             1630.00,491.00 1605.00,495.00 1605.00,495.00
             1605.00,474.79 1608.98,484.41 1609.00,469.00
             1609.00,469.00 1609.00,441.00 1609.00,441.00
             1608.99,433.51 1607.29,426.29 1599.96,422.45
             1596.23,420.50 1590.22,421.00 1586.00,421.00
             1586.00,421.00 1559.00,421.00 1559.00,421.00
             1547.59,421.06 1541.16,427.47 1541.00,439.00
             1541.00,439.00 1541.00,470.00 1541.00,470.00
             1541.05,480.13 1542.88,477.97 1544.75,484.00
             1545.21,486.62 1545.00,492.08 1544.75,494.75
             1544.75,494.75 1535.00,494.75 1535.00,494.75
             1535.00,494.75 1522.00,491.00 1522.00,491.00
             1522.00,491.00 1420.00,491.00 1420.00,491.00
             1420.00,491.00 1395.00,495.00 1395.00,495.00
             1395.00,495.00 1395.00,491.00 1395.00,491.00
             1395.03,477.76 1398.84,482.45 1399.00,471.00
             1399.00,471.00 1399.00,386.00 1399.00,386.00
             1399.00,386.00 1399.00,231.00 1399.00,231.00
             1398.98,215.59 1395.00,225.21 1395.00,205.25
             1395.00,205.25 1405.00,205.25 1405.00,205.25
             1405.00,205.25 1418.00,209.00 1418.00,209.00
             1418.00,209.00 1451.00,209.00 1451.00,209.00
             1451.00,209.00 1475.00,205.00 1475.00,205.00 Z
           M 2035.00,1255.00
           C 2035.00,1255.00 2035.00,1260.00 2035.00,1260.00
             2034.92,1272.31 2031.02,1266.58 2031.00,1281.00
             2031.00,1281.00 2031.00,1449.00 2031.00,1449.00
             2031.02,1464.41 2035.00,1454.79 2035.00,1474.75
             2035.00,1474.75 2025.00,1474.75 2025.00,1474.75
             2025.00,1474.75 2012.00,1471.00 2012.00,1471.00
             2012.00,1471.00 1910.00,1471.00 1910.00,1471.00
             1910.00,1471.00 1885.00,1475.00 1885.00,1475.00
             1885.00,1475.00 1885.00,1465.00 1885.00,1465.00
             1903.68,1465.00 1894.73,1468.98 1910.00,1469.00
             1910.00,1469.00 2010.00,1469.00 2010.00,1469.00
             2012.98,1469.00 2016.18,1469.16 2018.99,1467.99
             2023.12,1466.28 2027.05,1461.22 2028.35,1457.00
             2028.35,1457.00 2029.00,1425.00 2029.00,1425.00
             2029.00,1425.00 2029.00,1281.00 2029.00,1281.00
             2028.98,1267.66 2023.60,1261.02 2010.00,1261.00
             2010.00,1261.00 1916.00,1261.00 1916.00,1261.00
             1916.00,1261.00 1770.00,1261.00 1770.00,1261.00
             1767.02,1261.00 1763.82,1260.84 1761.01,1262.01
             1756.88,1263.72 1752.95,1268.78 1751.65,1273.00
             1751.65,1273.00 1751.00,1305.00 1751.00,1305.00
             1751.00,1305.00 1751.00,1449.00 1751.00,1449.00
             1751.01,1456.49 1752.71,1463.71 1760.04,1467.55
             1763.77,1469.50 1769.78,1469.00 1774.00,1469.00
             1774.00,1469.00 1800.00,1469.00 1800.00,1469.00
             1815.27,1468.98 1806.32,1465.00 1825.00,1465.00
             1825.00,1465.00 1825.00,1474.75 1825.00,1474.75
             1825.00,1474.75 1815.00,1474.75 1815.00,1474.75
             1815.00,1474.75 1802.00,1471.00 1802.00,1471.00
             1802.00,1471.00 1769.00,1471.00 1769.00,1471.00
             1769.00,1471.00 1745.00,1475.00 1745.00,1475.00
             1745.00,1475.00 1745.00,1470.00 1745.00,1470.00
             1745.08,1457.69 1748.98,1463.42 1749.00,1449.00
             1749.00,1449.00 1749.00,1281.00 1749.00,1281.00
             1748.98,1265.59 1745.00,1275.21 1745.00,1255.00
             1745.00,1255.00 1749.00,1255.00 1749.00,1255.00
             1749.00,1255.00 1770.00,1259.00 1770.00,1259.00
             1770.00,1259.00 2010.00,1259.00 2010.00,1259.00
             2010.00,1259.00 2035.00,1255.00 2035.00,1255.00 Z
           M 1054.75,2095.00
           C 1055.00,2097.92 1055.21,2103.38 1054.75,2106.00
             1053.06,2111.36 1051.12,2110.34 1051.00,2119.00
             1051.00,2119.00 1051.00,2219.00 1051.00,2219.00
             1051.02,2234.41 1055.00,2224.79 1055.00,2244.75
             1055.00,2244.75 1045.00,2244.75 1045.00,2244.75
             1045.00,2244.75 1032.00,2241.00 1032.00,2241.00
             1032.00,2241.00 999.00,2241.00 999.00,2241.00
             999.00,2241.00 975.25,2245.00 975.25,2245.00
             975.00,2242.08 974.79,2236.62 975.25,2234.00
             976.94,2228.64 978.88,2229.66 979.00,2221.00
             979.00,2221.00 979.00,2121.00 979.00,2121.00
             978.98,2105.59 975.00,2115.21 975.00,2095.25
             975.00,2095.25 985.00,2095.25 985.00,2095.25
             985.00,2095.25 998.00,2099.00 998.00,2099.00
             998.00,2099.00 1031.00,2099.00 1031.00,2099.00
             1031.00,2099.00 1054.75,2095.00 1054.75,2095.00 Z
           M 3447.00,2899.00
           C 3440.66,2897.20 3422.63,2898.43 3415.00,2898.18
             3415.00,2898.18 3379.00,2898.18 3379.00,2898.18
             3379.00,2898.18 3366.99,2898.18 3366.99,2898.18
             3366.99,2898.18 3361.42,2898.87 3361.42,2898.87
             3361.42,2898.87 3355.00,2898.04 3355.00,2898.04
             3344.76,2897.54 3340.14,2901.77 3340.00,2912.00
             3339.93,2917.84 3339.11,2925.22 3345.10,2928.55
             3349.34,2930.90 3353.58,2929.57 3358.00,2929.77
             3358.00,2929.77 3366.00,2929.77 3366.00,2929.77
             3366.00,2929.77 3413.00,2929.77 3413.00,2929.77
             3421.78,2929.42 3439.43,2931.15 3447.00,2929.00
             3447.01,2931.77 3446.67,2936.29 3448.74,2938.40
             3451.05,2940.76 3464.95,2940.76 3467.26,2938.40
             3469.33,2936.29 3468.99,2931.77 3469.00,2929.00
             3474.26,2930.50 3487.74,2929.97 3494.00,2930.00
             3504.82,2930.06 3502.45,2932.75 3511.00,2932.98
             3523.14,2933.32 3518.81,2930.02 3532.00,2930.00
             3532.00,2930.00 3619.00,2930.00 3619.00,2930.00
             3630.80,2929.94 3632.98,2926.21 3633.00,2915.00
             3633.01,2907.54 3633.86,2898.49 3624.00,2897.23
             3618.29,2896.49 3615.45,2899.85 3611.00,2901.09
             3611.00,2901.09 3599.00,2901.09 3599.00,2901.09
             3599.00,2901.09 3576.00,2901.09 3576.00,2901.09
             3569.17,2899.98 3573.24,2897.81 3559.00,2898.00
             3550.73,2898.11 3551.68,2899.93 3545.00,2901.12
             3545.00,2901.12 3530.00,2901.12 3530.00,2901.12
             3530.00,2901.12 3502.00,2901.12 3502.00,2901.12
             3502.00,2901.12 3492.00,2901.88 3492.00,2901.88
             3484.85,2901.36 3481.54,2895.44 3469.00,2899.00
             3468.97,2895.56 3469.08,2892.17 3466.99,2889.21
             3463.30,2883.98 3453.87,2883.66 3449.65,2888.39
             3446.93,2891.45 3447.04,2895.19 3447.00,2899.00 Z" />
</svg>
```

I would need to replace each number inside the string to the closest number divisible by 70. Once that's done it's very likely that there will be duplicate paths so they should be removed until only one remains. Problem is I have absolutely no idea how to best achieve that in python.

For the first part perhaps using regex to find all numbers and for each replace with something like:
`round(n / 70) * 70`

For the second, I'm not sure yet if each line of 6 numbers would be equal to another full line, or only some of the numbers.

Comment: https://nerd.mmccoo.com/2018/01/11/understanding-and-parsing-svg-paths/ has an explanation of parsing SVG files.  note that your question is very much offtopic for this site, you've not included any code and there are a vast number of ways of approaching this problem

Comment: Thank you for the link @SamMason. I managed to solve the first problem using regex, first grabbing only the paths and then using `re.sub(r"\d+.\d+", lambda exp: str(round(float(exp.group()) / 70) * 70.0) + '0', coordinates)` to move everything to the nearest grid vertex.